# De que manera puedo establecer la posición del punto decimal en un input numérico de manera que siempre se posicione después del segundo numero

Tags: html, input, numberformat, input-type

Debe funcionar de la siguiente manera, por ejemplo si tecleo **12345** debe mantener la posición del punto **12.3450**. Debe también manejar siempre 2 números antes y 4 después del punto de manera que permita que se ingrese un numero digamos **1234** en este caso debería de completar con 0's **12.3400** o caso contrario, si se excede, solo tomara los primeros 6 dígitos, aunque si se ingresara un solo digito, al perder el foco debería de agregar un cero al principio, por ejemplo si se ingresa **5** debería de dar formato **05.0000**. Y asegurar también que si se teclea un numero como **123.456** el punto decimal se ignore o cambie de posición **12.3456**.
Esto lo debo aplicar a un sistema existente en el que se enfrenta la problemática al momento de capturar el dato en un formulario, desafortunadamente este sistema ya esta implementado y se utiliza de hace años, ya se tienen establecidas validaciones y restricciones que claramente no fueron desarrolladas debidamente, lo que me impide realizar cambios mayores en diseño o estructura de datos. Con esto me aseguraría que en futuras capturas se respete el formato **00.0000**, el cual es necesario al momento de realizar cálculos ya establecidos.
Como plus, me gastaría que el punto decimal, sea siempre visible en el input, esto no es necesario, pero de esta manera creo que podría dar a conocer el formato requerido incluso antes de teclear, ya que ni con un placeholder, ni con cursos se ha logrado concientizar a los capturistas sobre la importancia de capturar correctamente los datos.

Yo desarrolle la siguiente solución, pero no estoy seguro que sea lo mas adecuado tomando en cuenta que será integrado a un sistema ya desarrollado.

```js
   <script>
    $(function () {
      $("#CampoInput").on("focusout", function () {
        var inputValue = $(this).val();

        // Eliminar cualquier punto decimal antes de formatear
        inputValue = inputValue.replace(".", "");

        // Tomar solo los primeros 6 dígitos
        inputValue = inputValue.substring(0, 6);

        var formattedValue = formatearNumero(inputValue);
        $(this).val(formattedValue);
      });

      function formatearNumero(numero) {
        // Si el valor es igual a '1' o comienza con '1' seguido de ceros
        if (numero === '1' || numero.match(/^10*$/)) {
          return '01.0000';
        }

        // Obtener los primeros dos caracteres
        var primerosDosCaracteres = numero.substring(0, 2);

        // Obtener el resto de la cadena después de los primeros dos caracteres
        var restoDeLaCadena = numero.substring(2);

        // Rellena con ceros a la izquierda si es necesario
        primerosDosCaracteres = primerosDosCaracteres.padStart(2, '0');

        // Rellenar con ceros a la derecha si es necesario (para tener 4 decimales)
        restoDeLaCadena = restoDeLaCadena.padEnd(4, '0');

        // Verificar si ya hay un punto decimal en los primeros dos caracteres
        if (!primerosDosCaracteres.includes(".")) {
          // Agrega el punto decimal entre los primeros dos caracteres y el resto de la cadena
          primerosDosCaracteres += ".";
        }

        // Concatenar los resultados con el formato deseado
        var resultado = primerosDosCaracteres + restoDeLaCadena;

        return resultado;
      }
    });
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Formateo de Número</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <label for="CampoInput">Ingresa un número:</label>
  <input type="text" id="CampoInput">
</body>
</html
```

Comment: Lo que buscas se llama _"input mask"_. Podrías ver [este _plugin_](https://imask.js.org/) hecho con Javascript. Otras opciones suelen usar 2 elementos `input` uno de ellos escondido. Pero con Javascript suele ser sencillo realizar esta tarea una vez que sabes definir el patrón que deseas emplear. Toma en cuenta que los valores del elemento `input` son siempre de tipo cadena de texto, será tu responsabilidad *parsear* el valor si deseas convertirlo o usarlo como valor numérico.

Comment: Gracias MauricioContreras, ya habia revisado esa documentacion, sin embargo, no logra cumplir todos los requerimentos. La respuesta de @Yussef me parece la ideal, en ella resalto un detalle que no habia tomado en cuenta, que un numero ingresado no puede ser mayor a 99 puesto que el punto se recorre ademas incluyo la validacion de solo numeros que tampoco habia tomado en cuenta. Si consideras que si existe manera de utilizar "input mask" sin mayor complicacion te agradeceria alguna referencia puesto que yo no logre obtener el resultado con ello.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que te falta validar si la entrada es un número o no, por ejemplo que no sea "ABCDEF".

Para formatear como tu quieres puedes usar [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/format), luego tu tienes un caso muy particular, que sucede cuando el número ingresado es mayor a `99`, por ejemplo `123` pasa a ser `12.3`, entonces solo para estos casos debes reformar el número en consecuencia

Ejemplo:

```js
function formatear(valor){
  let valorNumber = Number(valor);
  
  if(!valorNumber){ //validamos si es número
     return "00.0000"; //podemos retornar ceros o una excepcion
  }

  if(valorNumber>99) {
    const valorString = String(valorNumber).replace(".","");
    valorNumber = valorString.substring(0,2) + "." + valorString.substring(2);
  }

  const options = {
    minimumIntegerDigits:2, //2 dígitos a la izquierda
    minimumFractionDigits:4,  //4 la parte decimal
    maximumFractionDigits:4,
    useGrouping: false //quitamos el separador de miles
  };

  return new Intl.NumberFormat('en', options).format(valorNumber);  
}

console.log(formatear("12345"));
console.log(formatear("1234"));
console.log(formatear("5"));
console.log(formatear("123.456"));
console.log(formatear("ABDCR"));
console.log(formatear("123452321332"));
```

---

Ahora para agregar el punto, puedes usar lógica parecida en el evento `input`, pero no aplicas el formato final (esto lo haces cuando pierda el foco (evento blur))

```js
CampoInput.addEventListener("blur",formatear);
CampoInput.addEventListener("input",addPunto);
function formatear(e){
  let valorNumber = Number(e.target.value);
  
  if(!valorNumber){ //validamos si es número
     e.target.value = "00.0000"; //podemos retornar ceros o una excepcion
     return;
  }

  if(valorNumber>99) {
    const valorString = String(valorNumber).replace(".","");
    valorNumber = valorString.substring(0,2) + "." + valorString.substring(2);
  }

  const options = {
    minimumIntegerDigits:2, //2 dígitos a la izquierda
    minimumFractionDigits:4,  //4 la parte decimal
    maximumFractionDigits:4,
    useGrouping: false //quitamos el separador de miles
  };

  e.target.value = Intl.NumberFormat('en', options).format(valorNumber);  
}
function addPunto(e){
  if(e.target.value.length>2) {
    let valorString = e.target.value.replace(".","");
    valorString = valorString.substring(0,2) + "." + valorString.substring(2);
    e.target.value =valorString;  
  }

 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="CampoInput">
```

Comment: Si escribo un valor no numérico en el `input`, este muestra `NaN` y se bloquea, dejando el `input` inutilizable.